# How to change where propietary code is loading a lib from on Android?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

Ok, so I am developing an Android app that requires a massive proprietary native lib. This greatly increases the deploy time from AS, which is very annoying. I'd like to dynamically load the library from the shared storage rather than including it in each download.

However, I can't just use `System.load("/data/data/com.package.app/extraLib.so");` because this lib also comes with a proprietary Java wrapper, and inside that wrapper `System.loadLibrary("Library");` is being called. Thus, if the lib isn't included in AS, the proprietary code will crash with an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

I tried to manually copy the lib into the `/lib` folder of my app's protected storage. However, for some reason the `/lib` folder is write-protected. (Yes I was copying from my app's Java code, not from a file explorer app, so root should not be required.)

Is there any way to change where the proprietary code loads the lib from without reverse engineering it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Warning! You should only do this for development, never for a release app!

With this approach, your app will be vulnerable to a code injection attack.

---

Well, I found a way to do it. I replaced the real library in the libs folder of AS with a dummy one that only contains this code:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compiled that into a `.so` file and renamed it to the name of the original library, and inserted it into the libs folder of my project.

Then, in the `onCreate()` method of my main activity, I did:

```
    File fileOnSharedStorage = new File("/mnt/sdcard/libTest.so");
    File fileInProtectedStorage = new File("/data/data/com.package.myapp/extra/libTest.so");
    File folder = new File("/data/data/com.package.myapp/extra/");

    if (!folder.exists())
    {
      folder.mkdir();
    }

    if(!fileInProtectedStorage.exists())
    {
      try
      {
        copyFile(fileOnSharedStorage, fileInProtectedStorage);
      } catch (IOException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    System.load("/data/data/com.package.myapp/extra/libTest.so");
```

And it works!

Comment: Congratulations on demonstrating how to develop an insecure app, one that is vulnerable to a code injection attack!

Comment: @CommonsWare this is only to speed up development. **The release app will have it included the normal way**

Comment: @CommonsWare You should read [perfect software -- and other illusions about testing](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4060560-perfect-software--and-other-illusions-about-testing). How do we know that the massive native library is immune to code injection, or the os, or any other part of the code?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: We don't. Just because we don't know if every door and window is locked does not mean we intentionally unlock a door. In this case, anyone with write access to external storage can swap in a different `.so`. The app will copy that modified `.so` and execute that code. This is the definition of a code injection attack.

Comment: @AndroidDev: Thanks! That helps!

Comment: @CommonsWare It is also one of the original intents to using shared libraries; that an external library **can** be upgraded and used without necessarily updating (or even recompiling) the linked library. For development use, code injection is a feature.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: "that an external library can be upgraded and used without necessarily updating (or even recompiling) the linked library" -- which is why a lot of modern software development has been running away from shared libraries. Even in situations where shared libraries are still used, generally they are in read-only locations, where updates are controlled. The scenario in this answer is *very* uncontrolled.

Comment: @CommonsWare well actually, unless the app is uninstalled, the copy code would only copy it once. That of course doesn't change the fact that it's a bad idea for a release app, but for development I don't see any problem with it.

Comment: @AndroidDev: Oh, for development, it's fine for devices that don't leave the lab. I'm surprised that Instant Run doesn't handle this situation for you. If the `.so` isn't changing, I would have expected Instant Run to not copy it over on each deploy, just sporadically (when a full APK push is needed). Perhaps there are limitations on Instant Run and JNI stuff, or perhaps the full-APK push is needed more often in your case.

Comment: *Perhaps there are limitations on Instant Run and JNI stuff* [indeed there are](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#build-run-sample)